# Why do I get a include <windows.h> error when developing on a Windows machine in C?

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I am new to C and I am trying to compile a code that uses am external library. Therefore, I am following [these](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) steps for linking a library. But at the very first one

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic PICASO_SERIAL_4DLIBRARY.C
```

I get this

```
PICASO_SERIAL_4DLIBRARY.C:1:0: error: -fpic ignored for target (all code is position independent) [-Werror]
#include <windows.h>


cc1plus.exe: all warning being treated as errors
```

additionally undder # there is a arrow above. I tried googling it but I could only find out that this is a Linux problem and not a Windows one (I am developing on Windows now) and the I followed [these steps](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C-Program-Using-the-GNU-Compiler-(GCC)) to install gcc. an compiling other small projects work, too.

Anyone any idea, why this doesn't work?

Comment: What if you remove the `-fpic`? The warning doesn't say anything about `windows.h` and seems to assign a command-line error to the first line in the file.

Comment: I would recommend installing Linux on your laptop. It is a very nice platform to learn about C programming, and you can study most of the source code, since it is made of free software.

Comment: @Basile That's a ludicrously drastic suggestion. You seem to apply that good tools for C don't exist on Windows. I'm sure you know that is not so.

Comment: It is a recommendation (anda biased opinion), and I just say that Linux is a nice platform to learn about C programming, and that studying source code of free software would be helpful. BTW, I'm coding since 1974 and never used Windows (for coding or other serious tasks)

Comment: @Basile The asker is trying to compile code designed for Windows. Switching to Linux won't help that. It's perfectly possible to learn and do C programming on many different platforms. Linux and Windows being two examples.

Comment: I tried both platforms and also on Mac, what setup would you recommend to learn? For Windows I used this http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C-Program-Using-the-GNU-Compiler-(GCC) and for Linux the preinstalled version of gcc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mention of `#include <windows.h>` is incidental. That just happens to be the first line of code.

The compiler tries to associate a line of code with the error to help you find the problem. But in this case the code is irrelevant. The error is in the command line and you will get a failure no matter what the code is. But because the compiler is coded to always associate a line of code with an error, it decides, arbitrarily, to point the finger at the first line of code.

Because you use `-Werror`, warnings are treated as errors. The compiler therefore converts a warning about an ignored option to emit position independent code into an error. The error message states this very clearly:

> PICASO_SERIAL_4DLIBRARY.C:1:0: error: -fpic ignored for target (all code is position independent) [-Werror]

I suspect you glazed over when reading the error message, and turned your attention to the line of code that was highlighted. Always read error messages carefully!

To resolve the error, remove the `-fpic` option from your command line.

Comment: ok so I leave it out and then a long error comes that ends with this: `In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:50:0,
                 from PICASO_SERIAL_4DLIBRARY.C:1:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1364:26: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void* C
reateFileA(LPCSTR, DWORD, DWORD, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, DWORD, DWORD, HANDLE)' [
-fpermissive]
 WINBASEAPI HANDLE WINAPI CreateFileA(LPCSTR,DWORD,DWORD,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,D
WORD,DWORD,HANDLE);`

Comment: what does that mean? Thank you btw for the detailed answer

Comment: Don't know. That's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compile without `-fpic`.  This flag is inappropriate for the mingw-w64 target.